# Advantages to a negative power supply rather than ground?

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit

My question is basically

> Is there any advantage to using a negative power supply rather than ground? In what contexts does this matter and, if so, why?

I had thought that voltage since is a relative measurement, it shouldn't matter if I operate my system between 30 V and 0 V (to be sure, I am defining 0 V as a strong Earth ground but perhaps my understanding of grounding is naive) or 15 V and -15 V. Can anyone elaborate on this for me?

Comment: This is a repost of your [previously deleted question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/692847/advantages-to-a-negative-power-supply-rather-than-ground); this is not allowed. If you have new information to add, edit the original, don't repost.

Comment: It is a repost because the question was being distracted from due to concerns about ChatGPT which don't bear on the question itself. I am really eager to get an answer to this and didn't want to have that distraction. Hopefully this is OK. @Hearth

Comment: Others may disagree, but I don't think "really eager to get an answer" is a valid reason to ignore site rules.

Comment: @EE18 FYI, what you're supposed to do is just edit the question. You can change the title and everything on stack exchange.

Comment: Example: Single bjt amp shifts the operating point because of drifts. On other hand bipolar amp with dual supply and matched bjt pair “always” holds the middle. In case of DC amps it is very important.

Comment: @ee18 Please do not delete and repost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage of having symmetrical supplies is that there are 3 rails instead of 2. With 1 in the middle of the other 2. +15V, 0V, -15V for example, vs 30V, 0V. That's not just a shift. There's another rail which can source or sink current.

Lets look at an audio circuit with positive only supply to see why this can be helpful. Most op amps don't work properly within 1-2V of the supply rails. Therefore you're going to need to keep your AC signal centered on VCC/2 (15V).

Many places in your circuit will require that 15V VCC/2 voltage for reference. You can generate it using a voltage divider easily, but there are some complications:

1. The voltage divider will have a high output impedance (so it will not be accurate if you dump much current into it).
2. It wastes power.
3. Even if you buffer it with an op-amp, the impedance will still be higher than an actual power rail.
4. If you draw a lot of current and the supply sags, the VCC/2 voltage will change. The caps in your circuit won't "know" that of course, so this disturbance will be coupled into your signal.

Having a positive and negative supply avoids all those issues (and likely more that I haven't thought of).

Comment: Sorry, I see now it's in reference to the 30 V situation. My bad!

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, the argument is that having 0 V as your "middle rail" or "intended DC bias" is unique (as contrasted e.g. with 15 V in a 30/0 system) because you can actually make a physical connection to Earth ground with nominally no fixed current flowing, and so since this is a "hard" rail with low output impedance (I'll take for granted that a true rail has low output impedance) we get better performance?

Comment: If we compare a circuit with power rails 15V,0V,-15V to one with 30V,15V,0V where the 15V rail can source or sink current, indeed there is not much difference. There is one difference which another answer pointed out. With the former, the AC waveform is centered on 0. That's more useful than AC with a DC offset. The offset can be removed with a DC blocking cap, but that can distort the signal if the frequency is low.

Comment: But I just wanted to clarify, you are saying that in the 30 15 0 case it is *not* the case in general that the middle 15 is a perfect source or sink (or at least it's much harder to arrange that this is so, unlike the 0 rail in the 15 0 -15 case)? And, if so, would it be able to specify *why* that is?

Comment: Generally voltage regulator circuits assume that you will only draw source current from the output not sink into it. So the 15V rail regulator in the 30, 15, 0 circuit would be different than a normal one.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I follow but maybe when I have more analog experience I will. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on where the signal voltage range lies with respect to *your* definition of "0 V" (aka ground).

For signals on both sides of ground, it is prudent to place your 30 V supply such that it also spans positive and negative voltages around ground.

Though if your signal voltage range is between -556 V and -546 V, then you might prefer supply voltages rails of -566/-536 V instead.

Answer (score 1):

Single supply requires biasing up to mid-supply and adding ac coupling (dc blocking) capacitors, probably electrolytic. The capacitors will add distortion.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, for example, in the context of making use of a device such as an operational amplifier (or op-amp), which could be supplied with either +30VDC or 0VDC for VDD and VSS, or in a similar fashion with +15VDC and -15VDC;

The difference here is that, depending on your input and output voltage "wiggle" of positive and negative 180 degree to 360 degree fluctuation, the advantage of having a -15VDC rail is that there is an equal yet opposite voltage pulling, rather than pushing the amplified signal (from Vin to Vout).

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: *"I hope that makes sense."* - To me, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong. You can have an imaginary reference. Compared to that reference, a 0v to 30v supply could be translated as -30v to 0v. In a lot of cases, it does not matter how you look at it.

The negative supply (like the one you mentioned, -15v, +15v) with a 0v reference (like -15v, 0v, 15v) has a lot of applications. For example, if you are designing an analogue circuit with op-amps, the negative voltage could help simplify the design. Having a negative supply means, that in a chain of op-amps in a circuit, output of some of them can go below zero. If you don't have a negative supply, then you can't have an op-amp with an inverted configuration and positive input!

Another benefit of having a negative supply for circuits with op-amps is that most of the op-amps are not working great around supply voltages. Even a rail-to-rail op-amp will not be completely linear near the supply voltages. Having a 0v reference and positive and negative supply helps. The signal can be designed around the 0V reference and be far enough from the supply voltages.

[image source](https://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/Semi/SEMI_8.html)

[image: op-amp]

As you can see in the image, you will need two power supplies to create such a configuration.